# Preferable way to set background and font dynamically in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

I have to update the nodes styling dynamically based on my data. Mostly it will be background, border and font. I cannot define predefined css class names to define background color as the colors will be dynamic. Same as with border and fonts.

I am aware that I can set background to a Region in two ways. By constructing the style string and set in setStyle method

```
region.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getColorStr()+";");
```

or alternatively I can construct a Background object and set using setBackground.

```
Background background = new Background(new BackgroundFill(getColor(), new CornerRadii(0), Insets.EMPTY));
region.setBackground(background);
```

I am a bit confused to choose which option to go with. Mainly worried about the performance issue of one option over other. Can someone let me know which is most preferrable way to go with (considering performance) ? 
Just to let you know my CSS file is a heavy file with complete customisation of all controls. Can this be a factor to consider for performance if I go with setStyle method.

The same question when dealing with Border and Font as well.

Comment: You could try both options and profile your application to see which is more performant. If they both perform about the same choose the option you like best. Also, note that the `modena` theme of JavaFX rarely, if ever, uses actual `Border`s; instead, it uses multiple backgrounds with different insets.

Comment: @Slaw, Thank you for the suggestion. I will check with a demo to do the profiling and will update the results. Regarding the borders, I think i have to go with Border implementation only rather than background insets. Because my dynamic data will include info about the border styling as well (dashed, dotted, solid..) and also with dash array values.